# How to read the datetime property in sightly html (AEM 6.1)

Tags: aem, sightly

I have one property in my cq dialog whose xtype is datetime. Value is stored like this "2016-04-11T03:00:00.000-04:00" in cq and name of the property is eventDate.

I would like to know two things here -

1. How can i read the date and time from this property in sightly html.
2. When i passing this date as the parameter in my Use class (Java class), this is getting passed as null. However, when i pass currentPage.lastModified, then i can see the date value.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with code samples maybe?

You can read the property in Sightly HTML like any other property but there is no formatting for that, formatting in Java Use class is already answered by @Subhash below.

As for your other question, can you show the line of code you are using to read the date?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the approach using sightly.

To provide an alternate solution - 
You could probably used jcr api's on the node containing datetime property.
`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` api can be used to efficiently extract date and time. 
For eg:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
dateFormat.format(node.getProperty(eventDate).getValue().getDate().getTime())
```

Similarly to persist date in datetime you could probably use `com.day.cq.commons.date.DateUtil` api

```
node.setProperty(propertyName, DateUtil.parseISO8601(DateUtil.getISO8601Date(Calendar.getInstance())))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the missing part is, you are not adding the [use class](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html) inside your sightly. Your sightly should have this:

```
<div data-sly-use.eventUseObj = "com.test.models.EventModel" data-sly-unwrap />
```

The respective java use class should have overridden activate() method like this:

```
public class EventModel extends WCMUse {
    private String eventDate;

    @Override
    public void activate() {
        Calendar eventCalendar = getProperties().get("eventDate", Calendar.class);
        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        eventDate = outputFormat.format(eventCalendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

Now this date can be easily used back in sightly like this:

${eventUseObj.eventDate}

This will print the value of the date on page. There are ampty number of date patterns supported by [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and you may choose the one required.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example with javascript UseAPI, the logic should hold true with Java UseAPI

dateformater.js file :

```js
"use strict";
//dateformatter.js 
use(function () {
 var formattedDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(this.mask).format(this.date);
 return {
     formattedDate: formattedDate
    };
});
```

and HTL (Sightly) markup example :

```html
<h1 data-sly-use.formatter="${'dateformatter.js' @ date=properties.eventDate.time, mask='dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}">
    Event date formatted: ${formatter.formattedDate}
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sightly has built-ins that support formatting string, date and numbers. Here is how you can format date in a specific format.

```
${'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' @ format=obj.date, timezone='UTC'}
${'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' @ format=obj.date, timezone='GMT+02:00'}
```

The timezone parameter is optional, so if you want the time in the default timezone then you can just omit the timezone parameter.

```
${'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX' @ format=obj.date}
```

You can read more about it here - https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/1.3/SPECIFICATION.md#1222-dates